# Prove equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm given the following:

"Prove that the following four statements are equivalent"

1.) $n^2$ is odd

2.) $1-n$ is even

3.) $n^3$ is odd

4.) $n^2+1$ is even

Well my first assumption is

1.) $n^2 = 2k+1$ for some integer $k$

2.) $1-n = 2j$ which is $n=-2b+1$

3.) $n^3 =2i+1$

4.) $n^2+1 = 2l$ or $n^2= 2l-1$

Bu this is the point now where I'm a little stuck and have no clue what to do with this information? How do I prove that all these four are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe $n^2$ odd implies $n$ is odd, for the contrapositive states:

$n$ even implies $n^2$ even. **Proof:** If $n = 2k$ then $n^2 = 4k^2 = 2(2k^2)$ is even as well. **QED**

So: (1) implies $n$ odd.

---

To prove equivalences, then, we could reason as follows:

If (1) then $n$ is odd, so write $n = 2k + 1$, hence $1 - n = -2k = 2(-k)$ is even.

If (2) then $1 - n$ is even, so write $1 - n = 2k$, hence $n = 2(-k) + 1$ is odd. I assume you have seen (or can prove) that odd times odd is odd, so $n*n$ is odd, hence $n^3 = (n*n)*n$ is odd.

If (3) then $n^3$ is odd, which implies $n$ is odd by tackling the contrapositive ($n$ even implies $n^3$ even, since $n = 2k$ means $n^3 = 2(4k^3)$, an even number). Once we know that $n$ is odd, we can write $n = 2k+1$, so that $n^2 + 1 = (2k+1)^2 + 1 = 4k^2 + 4k + 2 = 2(2k^2 + 2k + 1)$ is even as desired.

If (4) then $n^2 + 1$ is even, so subtracting $1$ makes the result odd, i.e., $n^2$ is odd.

We have now proved: (1) implies (2) implies (3) implies (4) implies (1).

So all four statements are equivalent. **QED**

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For all four of those, can you deduce whether or not $n$ is odd or even?

Furthermore, can you deduce whether or not the statements are true or false based on whether or not $n$ is odd or even?

Comment: Can i basically start this off by assuming n is even or n is odd and then implement that in each?

Comment: That'll definitely get you where you need to go for the second part. It'll help for the first part too; just make sure you're careful to prove the right direction.